# How to get PermissionKind from BasePermissions?

Tags: permissions, csom, item-level-permissions, custom-permission-level, check-permissions

There is a simple function to [add permissions to collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.roledefinition.aspx):

```
// Set up permissions.
BasePermissions permissions = new BasePermissions();
permissions.Set(PermissionKind.ViewListItems);
permissions.Set(PermissionKind.AddListItems);
permissions.Set(PermissionKind.EditListItems);
permissions.Set(PermissionKind.DeleteListItems);
```

But how to get assigned permissions back from existing BasePermissions object? I cannot find a function for that. There is only a [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.basepermissions.has.aspx) to check, if specific kind of permission is assigned or not. How to get the list of all assigned PermissionKind's?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

After searching for a solution, I found nothing better than just sequentially checking all possible permissions to find right one as follows:

```
  PermissionKind kind = PermissionKind.EmptyMask;
  foreach (PermissionKind k in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PermissionKind)))
  {
    if (roleDefinition.BasePermissions.Has(k)) 
      kind = k;
    else break;
  }
```

Because integer values for enumeration consistently increase, this must stop cycle on maximum available permission. Hope somebody could find a better way.